# Is there a way to fix Invalid field path (``).issues arrises when accessing Firebase from Android App?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had android app working fine with Firebase Database. Recently I start getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid field path (``). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..' issue. The issue happens if I want to access or write any Collection or Document. In fact it happens every time  I am accessing Firebase from App for read or write operations. The issue is not caused due to blank or null keys of document which was normally found when searching for solution.

I thought issue was of older version being in used and hence upgraded to latest Gradle version but still problem is continuing. I also checked if document keys are not null or blank since on searching found issue could be due to blank keys as well. Dint find such cause as well. Further i also observed the problem comes in accessing any collection or document of the database. That makes me thinking it is not coding issue but possibly more of generic Firebase issue that occurs every time during read or write operations performed. Thoroughly checked documentation but dint get clue for resolving the issue. Hence reverted to seek expert help from you guys.

My current setting as follows :-

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  android {
          compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.support.android.designlibdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = 
       ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }
   }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
     'proguard-rules.pro'}
     }
     dataBinding {
    enabled = true}

   compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
 }

 dependencies {
  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
  // Have used to resolve errors of ViewModelProviders two lines
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
   annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'

 // ViewModel and LiveData
 // implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
 //  annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"

 // Room
 implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
 annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'

 // Paging
 //   implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha6-1"
 //Firebase
 // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
 // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1'
 //Firestore Storage
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
 // Image Liberary Fresco from Open Source Facebook developer
 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
 }
 //Firebase
 apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
 buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    //FIrebase
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

}

The code used for accessing FireBase is

```
   FirebaseFirestore
   db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new 
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

   DocumentReference docref = 
      db.collection("Forms").document("Carpenter");
   docref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
   OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
          .........

           } 
       }
    });
```

Error Message

```
  2019-10-29 09:58:58.077 4417-4417/com.support.android.designlibdemo 
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.support.android.designlibdemo, PID: 4417
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (21.2.0).
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3 
  (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.2.1:529)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown 
  Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
    (RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid field path (``). Paths 
    must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..'
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.
    AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.
    lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    firestore@@21.2.1:320)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.
    AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown 
    Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
    (Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$
    ScheduledFutureTask.run
    (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
     (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.
    AsyncQueueSynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.
   run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.2.1:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue this morning. 
This happened when I tried to update a collection in firestore. I tried to restart the app but it kept crashing. I decided to `clear the data of the app info` and open again then it worked.

What I noticed, it kept crashing because of the offline capability of firestore, so the data structure was saved before getting to the server. And since one of the collection had wrong inputs, it kept crashing whenever the app would restart.

Few things to crosscheck:

- start by clearing the existing app data
- check out the sub collections under a collection you are using. In my case the on the the HashMap value was null and check if the documents of that collection are well structured with valid data. [image]
- Make the data structure of the collection serializable
- update your firestore version in gradle currently `'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'`

Hope it helps.